# How can I smoothly "blend" between 2 STLs?

Tags: modeling

I have 2 STL files, and I'd like to join them (not only as "join them into a single object", but "physically" join them). I'm using blender 2.8.

I'll give an illustration right away to clear what I'm talking about:

[image]

The STL in the center is purely flat, while the STL around it is more complex.

Is there any way that I can make these 2 STLs "meet" more or less smoothly so that the gap is filled and I obtain a single STL? Please consider that there might be lots of vertices on both STLs, so manually moving the vertices one by one wouldn't be a viable solution for me ;)

I'm a total blender noob, so maybe I'm simply not looking at the right software?

Thanks a lot!
Arnaud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Select both objects and press CTRL+J to join them as one object.
- Then go into Edit Mode, Edge Select.
- Select the outer edge loop then the inner edge loop (or vice-versa)
- Menu>Edge>Bridge Edge Loops

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! Thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to merge them with Booleans, be that the BoolTools addon or modifier. Take a look!